# Is there any Alternate to system.drawing.drawing2D.GraphicsPath in skiasharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, skiasharp

In ASP .NET core Framework,system.Drawing is not available.So i am trying to use skiasharp.So is there any Alternate to system.drawing.drawing2D.GraphicsPath in skiasharp?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much `SKPath`. You can find a good few docs here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/SkiaSharp.SKPath

> A path encapsulates compound (multiple contour) geometric paths consisting of straight line segments, quadratic curves, and cubic curves.